# Permission denied while installing healpy-package via pip on OS X

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, pip, file-permissions, healpy

I'm running OS X 10.6.8 and installed Python2.7 and numpy using Homebrew.

Now I try to install healpy-package (http://healpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) using pip:

```
pip install healpy
```

This yields following error:

```
/bin/sh: /private/var/folders/YC/YCx+tzpeEv8DV202sTxfoE+++TI/-Tmp-/pip-build-valtterilindholm/healpy/healpixsubmodule/src/cxx/autotools/install-sh: Permission denied
make[1]: *** [install-libLTLIBRARIES] Error 1
```

I can post more of the logs if necessary but I'm pretty sure this is the stage at which installation fails.
I've tried to run pip as sudo and change permissions of /private/* using

```
chmod -R 777 /private
```

but nothing helps.

If that makes any difference I've moved from MacPorts to Homebrew following these instructions http://bitboxer.de/2010/06/03/moving-from-macports-to-homebrew/

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same issue.  I just downloaded the the package from pypi and ran the setup manually and it worked fine.  No idea why it didn't work with pip.

```
wget --no-check-certificate https://pypi.python.org/packages/source/h/healpy/healpy-1.6.3.tar.gz#md5=60152b75ee6e19b15e73ca21a3c4ddde
# Note that OS X doesn't ship with wget, so you might have to get the package 
# using a web browser.
tar -xvzf healpy-1.6.3.tar.gz
cd healpy-1.6.3
python setup.py install
```

Comment: Same problem, and same solution, with healpy 1.8.4, OS X 10.7.5 and python 2.7.